# What happened to libgreen?

Tags: rust, coroutine

As far as I understand libgreen [is not a part of Rust standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17325) anymore. Also I can't find a separate libgreen package. There are a few alternatives - [coroutine](https://github.com/rustcc/coroutine-rs), which does not provide actual green threads for now, and [green-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/green-rs), which is broken. Do I right understand that for now there is no lightweight Go-like processes in Rust?

Comment: A couple of other related things: [threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/threadpool), [mio](https://github.com/carllerche/mio).

Comment: Seconding Chris' comment: there is no one-size-fits-all when it comes to green-threading, so you have to choose your trade-off.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are correct that there's no lightweight tasking library in `std` (or the rest of the main distribution), that `green` doesn't compile and that `coroutine` doesn't seem to fully handle the threading aspect yet. I do not know of any other library in this space.

As for what happened: the RFC linked to by that issue—[RFC 230](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/0806be4f282144cfcd55b1d20284b43f87cbe1c6/text/0230-remove-runtime.md)—is the canonical source of information. The summary is that it was found that the method by which green threading/IO was handled (`std` tried to abstract across both models, allowing them to be used interoperably automagically) was not worth the downsides. Now, `std` aims to just provide a minimum base-line of useful support: for IO/threading, that means "thin", safe wrappers for operating system functionality.

Answer (score 19):

Read this https://aturon.github.io/blog/2016/08/11/futures/ and also:

[Steve Klabnik's response](https://plus.google.com/+nialldouglas/posts/AXFJRSM8u2t) in the comments:

> In the beginning, Rust had only green threads. Eventually, it was
>   decided that a systems language without systems threads is... strange.
>   So we needed to add them. Why not add choice? Since the interfaces
>   could be the same, why not abstract over them, and you could just
>   choose which one you wanted?
>
> At the same time, the problems with green threads by default were
>   becoming issues. Segmented stacks cause slow C interop. You need a
>   runtime to manage them, etc. Furthermore, the overall abstraction was
>   causing an unacceptable cost. The green threads weren't very green.
>   Plus, with the need to actually release someday looming, decisions
>   needed to be made regarding tradeoffs. And since Rust is supposed to
>   be a systems language, having 1:1 threads and basically no runtime
>   makes more sense than N:M threads and a runtime. . So libgreen was
>   removed, the interface was re-done to be 1:1 thread centric.
>
> ---
>
> The 'release someday looming' is a big part of it. We want to be
>   really stable with Rust, and with all the things to do to actually
>   ship a 1.0, we didn't want to crystallize an interface we weren't
>   happy with. Heck, we pulled out a lot of libraries that are even less
>   important for similar reasons, like rand. Engineering is all about
>   tradeoffs, and we decided to choose minimalism.
>
> > mio is a non starter for us, as are most of the other async i/o frameworks for Rust, because we need Windows and besides we don't want
> >     to get locked into an expensive to replace library which may get
> >     orphaned.
>
> Totally understood here, especially in the general case. In the
>   specific case, mio is going to either have Windows support, or a
>   windows-specific version of mio is going to be released, with a
>   higher-level package providing the features for all platforms. And in
>   this case, it's maintained by one of the people who's currently using
>   Rust heavily in production, so it's not likely to go away anytime
>   soon. But, unless you're actively involved, it's hard to know things
>   like that, which is, of itself an issue.
>
> One of the reasons we were comfortable removing libgreen is that you
>   can write your own libraries to do different kinds of IO. 1.0 is a
>   strong core that we feel good about stabilizing forever, not the final
>   bit. Libraries like https://github.com/carllerche/mio can test out
>   different ways of handling things like async IO, and, when they're
>   mature enough, we can always pull them back in the standard library if
>   need be. But in the meantime, it's just one line to your Cargo.toml to
>   add them in.

And such [text from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3c35mq/where_can_i_find_the_old_native_coroutine_mn/):

> Unfortunately they ended up canning the greenlet support because
>   theirs were slower than kernel threads which in turn demonstrates
>   someone didn’t understand how to get a language compiler to generate
>   stackless coroutines effectively (not surprising, the number of
>   engineers wired the right way is not many in this world, but see
>   http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2l0a4b/do_rust_web_servers_use_libuv_through_libgreen_or/
>   for more detail). And they canned the async i/o because libuv is
>   “slow” (which it is only because it is single threaded only, plus
>   forces a malloc + free per async operation as the buffers must last
>   until completion occurs, plus it enforces a penalty over synchronous
>   i/o see
>   http://blog.kazuhooku.com/2014/09/the-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-libuv.html),
>   which was a real shame - they should have taken the opportunity to
>   replace libuv with something better (hint: ASIO + AFIO, and yes I know
>   they are both C++, but Rust could do with much better C++ interop than
>   the presently none it currently has) instead of canning
>   always-async-everything in what could have been an amazing step up
>   from C++ with most of the benefits of Erlang without the disadvantages
>   of Erlang.

Comment: Also "*one of the reasons we were comfortable removing libgreen is that you can write your own libraries to do different kinds of IO*" (same link). Like with C++, (green) threading might be implemented as a library first.

Comment: I left some comments on that post, I think this is an incomplete perspective.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik your comments on that post were very helpful to read. Neat to come back and see that this is how they got there :)

Comment: Thanks @JackO'Connor !

Comment: "disadvantages of Erlang" such as what?

I don't program in or know Erlang; I am just curious and not looking to start a language argument.

Comment: @ZacB Neither do I

Answer (score 10):

For newcomers, there is now [`may`](https://crates.io/crates/may), a crate that implements green threads similar to goroutines.

Comment: Nice one! Have you tried it? It looks very promising!

Comment: @Yoric Haha, no, at that time, I saw it on the news, so I posted something here, but I never tried it. I don't need that TBH.